# how to specify at least one in a xsd:sequence

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a sequence

```
<xs:element name="XXXX">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="YY" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element ref="ZZ" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

but I would like that at least one element of YY or ZZ to be present, in the above
both are allowed to be missing.

Comment: Are YYs and ZZs both allowed to be present or just one of them?

Comment: yes i.e. "YY or ZZ" (but not YY=ZZ=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I belive this is what you're looking for:

```
<xs:element name="XXXX">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="YY" />
        <xs:element ref="ZZ" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: If you want at least one you need to change minOccurs to 1